# DDPG input incompatible in OpenAI Gym custom environment

Tags: reinforcement-learning, open-ai, gym, ddpg

I have a custom OpenAI Gym Boid flocking environment using StableBAselines3 for DDPG. This error I encounter occurred previously due to wrong input size of actions. But my reset function is correct, at least to me. Furthermore new input files are also of same size as the first. I can't seem to figure out the reason.

```
def reset(self):
    # print(self.counter)        
      self.agents = [Agent(position) for position in self.read_agent_locations(self.counter)]

    for agent in self.agents:
        agent.acceleration=np.round(np.random.uniform(-SimulationVariables["AccelerationInit"], SimulationVariables["AccelerationInit"], size=2), 2)
        agent.velocity=agent.acceleration * SimulationVariables["dt"]
        print(agent.position)
    observation = self.get_observation()

    
    print("Reset", self.current_timestep)
    self.current_timestep = 0 
    return observation
    



    def get_observation(self):
        observation = np.zeros((len(self.agents), 2), dtype=np.float32)

        for i, agent in enumerate(self.agents):

                observation[i] = [
                    agent.position[0],
                    agent.position[1],
                ]
         

        return observation.reshape((len(self.agents), 2))
```

Code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xRFF12KvA5ATCL2pwOtf0XgE2e2WRB9u/view?usp=sharing

Error:

```
CorrectConfigs\Config_0\config.json
CorrectConfigs\Config_0\config.json

[-1.4 -9.4]
[-4.6 -2.3]
[ 2.9 -0.7]
[8.9 4.8]
[ 9.6 -1.8]
[ 1.9 -5.3]
[ 1.7 -9.5]
[ 6.2 -0.1]
[-8.1  6. ]

a\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2155, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))     
    File "C:\Users\Cr7th\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2143, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\Cr7th\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2111, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "C:\Users\Cr7th\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "C:\Users\Cr7th\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\keras\engine\input_spec.py", line 298, in assert_input_compatibility 
        raise ValueError(

    ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 10), found shape=(None, 20)
```